# Changing color of cites with hypersetup not working

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, color, citing

I'm trying to change the colors of my cites. I would like to get a light blue color for them. I tried using `hypersetup` but it seems not to work. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[preprint,3p,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  citecolor=Violet,
  linkcolor=Red,
  urlcolor=Magenta}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Article}
\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}

I'm citing the cite \citep{Bishop}, why can't I change this color? 

\section*{References}

\bibliography{biblio}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}

\end{document}

\endinput
```

Here is what this code produces to me:

[image]

As you can see the color of the cite is blue, even though I have `citecolor=Violet`. Why is this not working?

Here is my `bibtex` entry:

```
@Book{Bishop,
    author = {C.M. Bishop},
    title = {Neural Networks for Pattern Recognition},
    publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    year = {1996}
}
```

and here you can find the bibtex-style:

http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle/elsarticle-harv.bst

Comment: It may be a rare case, but the problem for me is that disable draft mode for `hyperref` package works for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `colorlinks` cannot be enabled, after `hyperref` is loaded. Set the option as package option:

  ```
  \usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
  ```
- The color `Violet` is undefined, this can be fixed, for example, by setting option `svgnames` for package `xcolor`.
- As Augustin has already analyzed in his [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/246398/16967), class `elsarticle` defines the colors of all link types to `blue`. This is done via `\AtBeginDocument`. A later `\AtBeginDocument` can again overwrite the color settings as shown in the following example.

Test file (unnecessary packages for MWE removed):

```
\documentclass[preprint,3p,twocolumn,authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[table,xcdraw,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{natbib}  
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \hypersetup{
    citecolor=Violet,
    linkcolor=Red,   
    urlcolor=Magenta}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Article}
\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}

I'm citing the cite \citep{Bishop}.                                

\section*{References}

\bibliography{biblio}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remark:**

If you want to submit the article and the publisher requires the use of class `elsarticle`, then the publisher might not want that the user changes the link colors and should be asked before submitting.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is caused by the `elsarticle` class which defines the colour of the links and prevents you from redefining them. If you change the style to `article` everything will work.